# dynamic allocating memory for char array

Tags: c++

having some understanding issues with the next block of code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char *str = "hi";
    char *p = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; *(str + i); i++)
        *(p + i) = *(str + i);
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the result:

```
hi═¤¤¤¤
```

When i'm using debugger, i can see that my **p** points to an array of like 10 or 15 or some other amount of symbols (depends on compilation), so i'm getting extra symbols after "hi". BUT, when i'm using strcpy():

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char *str = "hi";
    char *p = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(p, str);
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i'm getting the result:

```
hi
```

So, can someone, please, explain to me, why am i getting such a result with the first example of a program and how to rework it to get the result like in the second example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never copy the string-terminator `\0`. But `strcpy` does.

Comment: `char *str = "hi";` isn't allowed in c++ anymore, though older version of c++ used to allow it for compatibility and some compilers allow it as an extension. String literals should only be pointed to by `const` pointers : `const char *str = "hi";`.

Comment: If you're using C++ use `std::string`. If you can't use `std::string`, use `malloc` for -compatible allocations. Anything allocated with `new` can't be sent to `free`.

Comment: @tadman why are you suggesting to use malloc? I fail to see the reason.

Comment: @SergeyA So that anything allocated here can be passed to C code that can then  `free` it. This is using C++ `new` to allocate C-style strings, which means that C++ "owns" this memory and C can't assume ownership. If this was pure C++ code then `std::string` would be here and none of this would be necessary.

Comment: @tadman first, I see no passing to see code which does `free`. Second, I would advocate that C code would not free something it didn't malloc. Overall, I find your advice unwarranted.

Comment: @SergeyA This code leaks memory, it doesn't properly `delete`. I'm just saying if you're interfacing with C code, it's best to use C allocations.

Comment: @tadman and I am disagreeing with you in a general way. An 'interaction' with C code doesn't warrant C allocations. If you know C code will be freeing the string, than yes, use malloc - but I would be super suspicious of the code which frees what it wasn't allocating. On any rate, this has nothing to do with the snippet, as there is no C interaction shown. The leak is real, but to cure it, OP has to `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the stopping condition of the loop, i.e. `*(str + i)`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; *(str + i) ; i++)
    *(p + i) = *(str + i);
```

Note that there is no comparison operator in the expression. When an expression like this is used in a context where a logical condition is required, there is an implicit comparison to zero, i.e. `*(str + i)` means the same thing as `*(str + i) != 0`.

Now it should be clear why the string remains unterminated: loop stops when it discovers null terminator, and does not copy it into the destination string.

A slightly more "cryptic" way of doing the same thing would be coupling the comparison with the assignment, the way K&R book did:

```
for (int i = 0 ; *(p + i) = *(str + i) ; i++)
    ;
```

Now the null test happens after the assignment, ensuring that the destination is null-terminated.

Comment: ok, now i understand my mistake, but why i'm creating the array for 10, 15 (etc.) amount of symbols and not for 3?

    char *p = new char[strlen(str) + 1];

Comment: Your array has the size of 3. Extra characters come from memory past the end of your allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding the terminating null character to `p`.

Add the line

```
*(p + i) = '\0';
```

after the `for` loop. However, to do that, you have to declare `i` before the `for` loop.

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; *(str + i); i++)
    *(p + i) = *(str + i);
*(p + i) = '\0';
cout << p << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to terminate the string in your first exaple with a zero:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char const *str = "hi";
    std::size_t length = std::strlen(str);
    char *p = new char[length + 1];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        p[i] = str[i];
    str[length] = '\0';
    std::cout << p << '\n';
    delete[] p;
}
```

Please mind: String literals are immutable so they should be pointed to by `char const*`s. The correct type to hold sizes of objects in memory or indexes into them is `std::size_t`, not `int`. If you do manual memory management you have to make sure that you free the allocated memory by passing pointers obtained using `new` to `delete` and pointers from `new[]` to `delete[]`.

You shouldn't do memory management manually though. Use containers like `std::string` or `std::vector` or at least smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>`.